# Rxjs interval on tab change slows down

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I am developing a firebase online exam app. In the game, I have progress bar that completes after 10 seconds and the user should complete the answer. I have used this interval function to animate the 10 seconds.

**.ts**

```
startGame() {
    interval(10)
      .pipe(take(1000))
      .subscribe((res) => {
         this.progressTimer += 0.1;
      })
      );
  }
```

**.html**

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progressTimer"></mat-progress-bar>
```

However I noticed when the tab is not active, the progress bar is very unstable or very slow. I don't want the user the switch tab and look for answers and go back to the app and continue. How do you handle cases like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=66078) you see that chrome has a minimum timer interval of 1000ms for background tabs, which means your 10ms callbacks will not get fired. You can increase the interval to 1000ms, and override the animation to make it smooth:

ts:

```
readonly progress$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(10),
  map((i) => (i + 1) * 10),
  startWith(0)
);
```

template:

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progress$ | async"></mat-progress-bar>
```

css override:

```
.mat-progress-bar .mat-progress-bar-fill {
  transition: transform 1000ms linear !important;
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ad2u47?file=src/app/progress-bar-determinate-example.html)

---

If it's precision you are looking for, the `Date.now()` will also not provide this, because it's easy to fake by changing the system time while an answer is in progress.

You say you are using `firebase`, if you are using the `firestore` database, you can use the [`firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#now) method to get the current server timestamp. However there will most likely be a short network delay in this, and your code will obviously look a bit different

Comment: Your solution looks fine. I am not concerned about precision. But why when I change tab and come back. The progress bar is going backwards then forward.

Answer (score 0):

Interval and Timeout are inaccurate. They only grantee calling method after specified time. According to this, progress can go slower when tab is inactive. I would recommend using timestamps difference.

```
startGame() {
  const gameStartTimestamp = Date.now();
  const gameEndTimestamp = gameStartTimestamp + 10000

  interval(100)
    .pipe(
      map(() => Date.now()),
      takeWhile(date => date < gameEndTimestamp)
    )
    .subscribe(date => {
      this.progressTimer = Math.round((now - this.gameStartTimestamp) / 100)
    })
);
```

I also forked Poul's demo and apply my changes there [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ad2u47-vnno7p)

Answer (score 0):

could you change your function to this function.
do not play the hard way if you could do it easy way.

```
timer;
startGame() {
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
     this.progressTimer = this.progressTimer + 10;
     if (this.progressTimer >= 100) {
       clearInterval(this.timer);
     }
  }, 1000);
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ad2u47-2ssky9?embed=1&file=src/app/progress-bar-determinate-example.ts)

Comment: Why when I change tab and come back. The progress bar is going backwards then forward. But the solution looks fine

Comment: When the progress bar is loading, change your tab, wait 4 seconds, come back. See the behavior of the progress bar

Comment: try it in your application and not in  stackblitz it works for me I guess